# Linq Query not giving the expected result

Tags: c#, linq

After a quite complicated rework of code I stumbled over a small part of code which is not giving me the expected result. The following Linq query should query the data contained in the main object by selecting only those containing a particular string.

The main list contains about 5500 entries. after execution of the Linq query, the secondary object contains still these 5500 entries. Am I blind or already mentally deranged? The CompanyName parameter contains a company which effectively exists.

UPDATE: If the data is taken from the cache the list contains all relevant entries, just the query seems to have no effect.

```
public List<Account> GetAccountsByValue(string CompanyName)
{
    string CacheKey = "Accounts";
    ObjectCache dataCache = MemoryCache.Default;

    if (dataCache.Contains(CacheKey))
    {
        var ResultCached = (IEnumerable<Account>)dataCache.Get(CacheKey);
        var ResultCached2 = from c in ResultCached
                            where c.Name.Contains(CompanyName)
                            select new
                            {
                              c.Name,
                              c.Street,
                              c.City,
                              c.ID
                            };
        var temp = ResultCached2.ToList();
        return temp;
    }
    else
    {
        IList<CrmAccount> Accounts = CrmServiceAgent.GetAccounts();
        var ResultNoCache = from CrmAccount f in Accounts
                            orderby f.DisplayName
                            select new Account(f);

        // put the data in the cache
        CacheItemPolicy cacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();
        cacheItemPolicy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddHours(4.0);
        dataCache.Add(CacheKey, ResultNoCache, cacheItemPolicy);

        return ResultNoCache.ToList();
    }
}
```

The List of data which is queried looks like this (in WCF Test Client)

[image]

Everything works fine, just only the query part is not having effect which means that again all entries are returned instead of only thos containing the query parameter.

[image]

UPDATE: 
Actually I get an Null Reference Exception, probably because the Name-Attribute of the first few entries is null....

This is throwing now the error:

```
var ResultCached3 = ResultCached.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(CompanyName)).ToList();
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the value assigned to CompanyName? Providing some sample data might also help.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. My psychic debugging skills tells me that `CompanyName` is an empty string.

Comment: Sorry, for the missing info...the ConpanyName is defined as parameter. This code snipped is part of a method accepting the parameter CompanyName

Comment: Please verify the contents of `CompanyName`, and post a [mcve].

Comment: Is "CompanyName" a ResultCached property?

Comment: sorry fo the confusion...added the whole method now

Comment: @SandroColletti None of the code that you added helps anyone else reproduce the problem.  All of the code you added is entirely irrelevant, and the information needed is still not shown.

Comment: `var temp = ResultCached.ToList();  return temp;` thus ignoring the result of your query (`ResultCached2`).

Comment: not to mention that your query result is a list of an anonymous type. `return ResultCached.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(CompanyName)).ToList()` should do it, for the first block.

Comment: @Servy
I know but unfortunately I can't post the whole implementation because this would mean to post all involved classes which are to many to post here. I thought maybe somebody would see a mayor error I don't see

Comment: @SandroColletti You don't' need to, and absolutely shouldn't, post your whole solution.  Virtually all of it is going to be irrelevant to reproducing the problem.  You need to provided the *smallest* program that you possibly can that still reproduces your problem.  That program will almost certainly be shorter than what you've currently shown.  If you aren't interested in giving anyone enough information to answer your question, then there's no point in even asking it.

Comment: I suppose, you mean `var temp = ResultCached2.ToList();`, don´t you?

Comment: @Servy
It's not quite fair to assume i'm not interested to give the appropriate information. my point is just to show this part of code in which the query part maybe contains already an error I don't see yet. If everybody finds the query correct, I will search deeper and outside this particular method and - if possible - provide more details.

Comment: @HimBromBeere
Yes correct...but this is not causing the issue...I have in any case always all list entries...the query has no effect actually

Comment: Could you try var resultCached3 = ResultCached.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(CompanyName)).ToList() ? What would it contain in your case?

Comment: Hi @rs232

Thank you for the hint but I get now a "null reference exception"...probably because the "name" attribute of the first few entries is null...see screenshot at the end of my post above. I'm just quite confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now fixed the whole thing. The data queried from the database now does not contain any null values anymore. The problem was, that mandatory fields where checked only in the frontend and not on database level. so data which usually is mandatory was imported as null values

so now in the List I have only "valid" data and now the linq query works as it should.

Thank you all for your hints ans suggestions!

kind regards
Sandro

Answer (score -3):

```
 var ResultCached2 = (from c in ResultCached
   where c.Name.Contains(CompanyName)
   select new
   {
    c.Name,
    c.Street,
    c.City,
    c.ID
   }).ToList();
```

Comment: write query in this way will give your desired result

Comment: this does not answer the question, it is basically the same code from the question